# How can i prevent scrolling the page to top when i close my css3 lightbox img?

Tags: css

That's my code. How can I prevent scrolling the page to top when i close my css3 lightbox img?

```
 <div class="col-sm-4">
 <div class="row d-info">
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
        <section id="gallery">
            <!-- thumbnail image wrapped in a link -->
            <section class="item">
                <a href="#imag16">
                    <img src="images/alarm/imag16.png" />
                </a>
            </section>
        </section>
        <div class="lightbox" id="imag16">
            <div class="box">
                <a class="close" href="#">X</a>
                <p class="title">External device</p>
                <div class="content">
                    <img src="images/alarm/imag16.png" />
                        <p class="desc">60 m outdoor • Quadruple beams • Digital   frequency conversion • Active infrared detector • Quadruple beams simultaneously blocked inspection • Infrared LED lighting • Digital wave filtering lighting</p>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
        <h2>External device</h2>
        <p class="font1">Quad Beam Detector</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/181/

```
$('a.closeButton').click(function(e) {
  //Do something here
   alert('Closed');

   return false; // prevent default click action from happening!
   e.preventDefault(); // same thing as above

});
```

Also you should use `button` instead `a` for closing

Comment: Thanks a lot , i changed it to button , but the first one still don't work , my be the <a href="#"> is the reason ?

Comment: @amy updated my answer, try fiddle and scroll to bottom and try to click on link, it wont scroll to top.

Comment: Thanks i think your answer is right but maybe i'v another thing make the scroll , try this   https://jsfiddle.net/ec8r6ysv/ it shows the problem